# Hard, store-bought cashews

Tags: cashews

I love cashews, I find them very nice and soft and really creamy like texture and they're the only nut I can eat right now.

I'm wondering recently I bought up a brand new container of cashews, but they are hard as peanuts and some of them are harder than peanuts.

Is there any way that I can soften them or did I just buy the wrong kind? What should I buy if I want that nice soft texture?

Comment: did you maybe buy roasted cashews instead of raw, or something like that?

Comment: Note that cashews are never sold truly raw, because they're seriously irritant. The un-roasted ones have still been steamed. (@Esther)

Comment: I always find the expensive ones from a company I've actually heard of, are invariably better than the random ones they stock in smaller stores.

Comment: @Tetsujin lidl own seem decent and consistent. I often stir fry them or toast them to add to pasta etc. for substance and protein as I don't really eat meat. I get through them quickly and I suspect the shop does too

Answer (score 1):

As I've accidentally noticed this morning, roasted salted cashews seem quite a bit softer having been left uncovered in a fairly humid room overnight.

That may not be a solution, but steaming them for a few minutes might be. Like peanuts, cashews soften if simmered in a sauce, to the extent that I prefer to toast them first so they retain some bite; simmering in water should have the same effect.

If your old pack had been open for some time, they may have gradually softened, increasing the contrast with the new ones.